# How to disable a button after click in limejs

Tags: limejs

How do I  disable a button after click in limejs? I have tried using

```
    this.disable()
```

but it does not work.

Comment: You should expand your code to show the context of *this* to get better quality answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [goog.events.listenOnce](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_events_events.js.html).  Identical signature to goog.events.listen and will only fire once.

Answer (score 0):

Try goog.events.listen and goog.events.unlisten:

```
goog.events.listen(my_button, ['mousedown','touchstart'],function_triggered_onClick);
goog.events.unlisten(my_button, ['mousedown','touchstart'],function_triggered_onClick);
```

goog.events.unlisten will disable the button untill code reaches goog.events.listen again